# pdf of the difference of two random variables

Tags: calculus, probability, normal-distribution, conditional-probability

Suppose we have a sample $X$ distributed as $X \sim \mathcal{N} (\mu, \sigma^2)$. I make $n$ draws from $X$, and I remove those elements that are greater or equal than $\phi$.

How can I calculated the new pdf of the distribution so created?

$X-nP(X| X \geq \phi)$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Exactly what distribution do you create from those $n$ draws? What does your notation $nP(X|X\ge\phi)$ mean?

Comment: Why are you speaking of pdf of *difference of two random variables* in your title? That does not really match with the body (which needs clarification) of your question.

Comment: When you remove the draws greater than or equal to $\phi$, do you mean you set them to zero?

Comment: It sounds like you want the distribution of a truncated normal.